# How to set up sge to prevent "dropped because overloaded" error?

Tags: sungridengine

I installed sge in a small HPC cluster, set openmpi as the pe method. I found sge assign jobs to execution hosts that do not have enough processors available. Hence I got error message "scheduling info:            queue instance "testq@hpc..." dropped because it is overloaded: np_load_avg=2.000625 (no load adjustment) >= 1.75" if I run qstat -j.

Where am I wrong here? Why sge cannot put the job waiting?

Comment: Did you set # slots available per node as resource: `qconf -rattr exechost complex_values slots=20,num_proc=20 $node_host_name`?

Comment: @Vince No. Seems your suggestion works. Thanks. Could you please make an answer so I can take it?

Comment: Sorry @Vince. Setting complex_values did not work. I found change load_thresholds of the queue from 1.75 to 1.0 did the trick. But not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: @Luke did you change it to 1.0, or 2.0?  I'm encountering a similar problem, and a temporary fix is to increase load_thresholds to be above the np_load_avg.